# SQL - Constraint to ensure value in one table is tied to the appropriate value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not entirely sure how to word this. I have 3 tables for a booking system consisting of **'Payments'**, **'Credit Cards'**, and **'Reservations'**.and I need to add a constraint to ensure that the Credit Card ID in the 'Payments' table belongs to the customer that made the reservation that is in the same row as the Credit Card ID number in the Payments table.

**Credit Cards** - containing the attributes "**CC_ID**", "Customer_ID", "Card_Number"

**Reservations** - containing the attributes "**R_ID**", "Schedule_ID", "Customer_ID"

**Payments**     - containing the attributes "**CC_ID**", "Reservation"

So I basically need to check that the CC_ID in **Payments**, which is tied to a Customer ID in **Credit Cards**, belongs to the same customer that made the reservation that is in **Reservations** and ultimately corresponds with the Reservation number in **Payemnts**. This would be an input contstraint when values are added to the Payments table, rather than manually checking to make sure it belongs to the customer upon entry.

Comment: Please add a tag for the database system you are using. Answer will depend on that

Answer (score 1):

One method to do what you want involves a trigger.  Simple constraints won't do . . . less you slightly change the data structure.

So, one method is to change `payments` to include `customer_id`.  I realize that this is redundant, but then you can use foreign key constraints.

```
alter table payments add customer_id  . . . ;

alter table reservations add constraint unq_reservations_2
    unique (customer_id, r_id);

alter table payments add constraint
    foreign key (customer_id, reservation) references reservations(customer_id, r_id);
```

Although both keys are not needed for the `reservation` table, having both allows you to create a foreign key constraint on both columns.